# What is the difference between these two enums

Tags: objective-c, enums, bit-manipulation

So in my my travelings i've alwasys seen enums defines like this (when a bit map is desired)

```
enum {
    UIControlStateNormal       = 0,                       
    UIControlStateHighlighted  = 1 << 0,                  // used when UIControl isHighlighted is set
    UIControlStateDisabled     = 1 << 1,
    UIControlStateSelected     = 1 << 2,                  // flag usable by app (see below)
};
```

However, I've just recently looked at the NSJSONSerilization class to come across an enum defined as so

```
enum {
    NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
    NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves     = (1UL << 1),
    NSJSONReadingAllowFragments    = (1UL << 2)
};
typedef NSUInteger NSJSONReadingOptions;
```

So I guess my question is what does the `UL` do. What is the difference between `1 << 1` and `1UL << 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++, `UL` just means the literal is an `unsigned long` integer type. The default integer literal is `int`.

Comment: Ahh so they are doing this because NSUInteger is a typdef of unsigned long. That makes senses. Thanks. Will accept your anser in 7 minutes when it lets me :) you answered too fast.

Answer (score 5):

There's no difference between `1 << 1` and `1UL << 1`, but there **can** be a difference between `1 << 33` and `1UL << 33`. Depending on platform, and `unsigned long` can get bigger than an `int`, so if the `enum` has lots of values, an `int` might not be safe to use.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, there is no difference in your code.

The type of `1` in the first is `int`, and the type of `1UL` in the second is `unsigned long`.

Answer (score 1):

The code will work the same, there is no real difference.

However, type of `1` in the first code is `int`, while the type of `1UL` in the second code is `unsigned long`.